CaptureStream stops on adding Video to Fabric.js
I have a Fabric.js canvas; and I capture the mediastream which then is displayed in the video. This works fine in the start; when I add the text to the Canvas it also shows in the video. The problem is that myVideo does no longer update as soon as I start playing htmlVideo that I've added to the canvas.
I can see htmlVideo appear in the Canvas and it plays there, but not in myVideo. The state of myVideo is still playing but it seems like there's no more data coming in, which makes me suspect that there's something incorrect with the setup of the captureStream or with the rendering in requestAnimFrame
Does anyone know why?


import {
    Canvas, FabricImage, FabricText, util
} from 'fabric'

const canvas      = new Canvas('myCanvas')
const video       = document.getElementById('myVideo')
const mediaStream = canvas.getElement().captureStream(30)

video.srcObject  = mediaStream
video.play()

// Add text after 5 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  const txt = new FabricText('Hello World', {
    fill: '#FFF',
    left: 10,
    top: 40,
  })

  canvas.add(txt)
  console.info(`Text added to canvas`)
}, 5000);

// Add video after 10 sec
setTimeout(() => {
  var htmlVideo = document.createElement('video') as HTMLVideoElement

  htmlVideo.src = 'http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4'
  htmlVideo.width  = 480
  htmlVideo.height = 360

  var fabricImage = new FabricImage(htmlVideo, {
      left: 200,
      top: 300,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      objectCaching: false
  })

  canvas.add(video)

  htmlVideo.play()
  console.info(`Video added to canvas`)
}, 10000);

util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
  canvas.renderAll()
  util.requestAnimFrame(render)
})
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="360" controls playsinline></video>



